# Bash text database file read in loop

Tags: arrays, database, bash, while-loop

Can anyone see the last syntax error I have made here? The issue is with incrementing the DB"X"FIELDS array. In a way, I'm simulating a mutlidimensional array by storing all records from each database into its own array so they can be called later. I can't figure out the syntax through to declare the DB array using an embedded variable that increments. Maybe I just need to Set the name first (including the variable, then declare the array.

```
function DATABASE.READ {
  cd databases
  DBARRAY=(*)
  cd ..
  local i
  local j
  for i in "${!DBARRAY[@]}"; do
    declare -a DB$iFIELDS                 ### Here is the problem. Declaring the array.
    while read LINE; do 
      for (( j=1; j<=25; j++ )); do
        VALUE="`echo $LINE | cut -d"|" -f"$j"`";
        DB$iFIELDS[$j]="$VALUE"           ### Also here, which I believe requires a different syntax
      done
    done < <(grep -v '#' databases/${DBARRAY[$i]})
  done
}
```

*** UPDATE ***

Ok, so I had a big realization that I was leaving out an entire dimension of the database. I have since revised the code to create the additional arrays to hold all database information. Yes I know this is starting to get a little out of hand. I appreciate all the help though. Thanks

```
function DATABASE.READ {
  cd databases
  DBARRAY=(*)
  cd ..
  local i
  local j
  local k
  i=1
  j=1
  for i in "${!DBARRAY[@]}"; do
    while read LINE; do
      declare -a "D${i}R${j}F"
      for (( k=1; k<=25; k++ )); do
        VALUE="`echo $LINE | cut -d"|" -f"$k"`";
        eval "D${i}R${j}F[$k]=\"$VALUE\""
      done
      let j=j+1
    done < <(grep -v '#' databases/${DBARRAY[$i]})
  done
  ########## EXAMPLE ECHO OF ONE SPECIFIC FIELD IN DATABASE1 RECORD1 FIELD1 ##########
  echo "${D1R1F[1]}"
}
```

*** UPDATE ***

THANKS to both of you. There is still a small logic error that I'm having trouble identifing, but I'm sure it's much simplier than what we were initially troubleshooting. The original issue appears to be resolved thanks to you guys. Here is the current code:

```
function DATABASE.READ {
  cd databases
  DBARRAY=(*)
  cd ..
  local i
  local j
  local k
  i=1
  for i in "${!DBARRAY[@]}"; do
    j=1
    while read LINE; do
      declare -a "D${i}R${j}F"
      for (( k=1; k<=25; k++ )); do
        VALUE="`echo $LINE | cut -d"|" -f"$k"`";
        printf -v "D${i}R${j}F[$k]" '%s' "$VALUE"
      done
      let j=j+1
    done < <(grep -v '#' databases/${DBARRAY[$i]})
    unset j
  done
  ########## ECHO TWO SPECIFIC FIELDS IN EACH DATABASE ##########
  echo "${D1R1F[1]}"
  echo "${D2R1F[1]}"
  echo "${D3R1F[1]}"
  echo "${D1R1F[3]}"
  echo "${D2R1F[3]}"
  echo "${D3R1F[3]}"
}
```

It looks like it's having trouble echoing both database 1 records. Trying to figure out what in the loop is goofing it up, or if maybe its a bigger problem.

*** SOLUTION ***

So it looks like the issue was with the database incrementing. When I don't specifically set i, and reference the databases starting at 0. It fixes it. Actually... it makes sense now. When the DB files are read into DBARRAY, they start with element 0 so yeah.....

So which of you do I give credit too? :)

Comment: `$iFIELDS` looks for a variable named `iFIELDS`, not a variable named `i` followed by the string `FIELDS`. Try `DB${i}FIELDS`. Also, the array access should look like `${DB${i}FIELDS[$j]}=...`, I would think... Although you may need to wrap that entire line in `eval`, because `bash` doesn't generally do computed variable names the way you are trying to do. So `eval "${DB${i}FIELDS[$j]}=\"$VALUE\""`, maybe...

Comment: var/anm.fcn: line 25: ${DB${i}FIELDS[$j]}="$VALUE": bad substitution

Comment: Your problem now seems to be on line: `declare -a "D${i}R${j}F"` because the `j=j+1` drags the `j+` part, you have to change `j=j+1` with `let j=j+1`, I have updated my answer, can you check it please?

Comment: Yeah I just caught that and updated above. I already added let.

Comment: The official issue is still this line: eval "D${i}R${j}F[$k]=\"$VALUE\"" The function successfully pulls all the records (I did some test echos), but VALUE is not being stored to the new array.

Comment: `eval` is evil. Don't use it!

Comment: Haha, yeah that wasn't my idea. To be honest, I don't understand it's purpose. I have never used it before. higuaro suggested it I think. Have a different solution other than new language?

Comment: @Atomiklan I already gave you an answer in (a comment of) your other post: use `printf`: `printf -v "D${i}R${j}F[$k]" '%s' "$VALUE"`

Comment: Oops sorry. I completely missed that. I just tried it though and the result is the same. VALUE is not getting stored to the array. Makes me think maybe something else is wrong.

Comment: Sorry I can't really help you, your code makes my eyes bleed (too many upper case letters, a horrible eval in the middle, backticks, useless pipes, not mentioning horrible design that leads to clunky workarounds that don't even work). No offense but this is a good example of horrible style (if you give me the permission I could show it as an example of things to not do).

Comment: I realize its not perfect. Far from it actually... I'm a nuclear physicist... not a programmer. I know my code must make real programmers cringe. Any help (even what not to do) is much appreciated.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf deal with the problem and stop complaining about it, if you're going to start fixing every OPs question, you should start somewhere else

Comment: Just a stupid remark: your `j` is never reset, so very likely there are no `D1R1F[1]` that are set. Apart from that, I can guarantee that your variables are set, and that `printf` is the way to do it, not `eval`.

Comment: @higuaro the problem is not from where the OP thinks it is. It's just that he's trying to retrieve a value that was never set.

Comment: You should either upvote or accept and answer (or both) only if you consider it useful or if it helps you to find a solution to your problem, neither is required, so feel free to do what you think suits better for your situation. You said that you're not a programmer but I got a couple of tricks from your code I didn't know, so thats a winning for me

Answer (score 0):

Try the following updated version:

```
function DATABASE.READ {
   cd databases
   DBARRAY=(*)
   cd ..
   local i
   local j
   local k
   i=1
   j=1
   for i in "${!DBARRAY[@]}"; do
      declare -a "DB${i}FIELDS"
      while read LINE; do
         declare -a "D${i}R${j}F"
         for (( k=1; k<=25; k++ )); do
            VALUE="`echo $LINE | cut -d"|" -f"$k"`";
   echo "VALUE = '$VALUE'"
            eval "D${i}R${j}F[$k]=\"$VALUE\""
   eval "echo ${D${i}R${j}F[$k]}"
         done
         let j=j+1
      done < <(grep -v '#' databases/${DBARRAY[$i]})
   done
   ########## EXAMPLE ECHO OF ONE SPEFIC FIELD IN ##########
   echo "${D1R1F[1]}"
}
```

Comment: mmm, weird, it should work, for example, the following test code works using `eval` as in the code: `DB1=(a b c);echo "${DB1[@]}";i=1; eval "DB${i}[0]=\"b\""; echo "${DB1[@]}"`, it prints `a b c` and then prints `b b c`

Comment: Currently there are three databases. i = 0 - 2. The first database is filled with test information in each record. If I try to do the following I get nothing. Maybe I'm just doing something really really stupid with the echo.  echo "${DB0FIELDS[3]}"

Comment: OH SHOOT... I forgot one very important piece... This does not account for each individual record. I will need a third layer to store every field from every record, from every database. Ugh need multidimensional arrays. Maybe it is time to move to a real language.

Comment: Normally I process the database info directly in the loop. I kept recalling the database over and over again though in code. So I have been trying to write a function to do it ONCE and pull everything (since it will use everything) that way its only calling the DB once in code.

Comment: I tried your update code above. Still no luck. VALUE is not being stored.

Comment: I tried replacing `eval` with `sh -c` still no luck... It complains in the assigment, added some debug `echo`'s though, check them out please

Comment: VALUE = 'Test' and Test on next line, but no output from array element. Weird right

Comment: The second output WAS from the array in your test above... So it is working, but for some reason the echo at bottom is incorrect. So whats wrong regarding the way I am formatting the array element for output?

Comment: @Atomiklan I think that you should check what @gniourf_gniourf said above about the `j` variable not being reset

Comment: VERY NICE GUYS! i can't believe I forgot to do that. Things are starting to work now. There are still a few logic errors I need to think through. Check back in a few mins for hopefully a final update.