# Bash array with variable

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

Any idea how I can declare a bash array with a variable embedded?

For example, `i` is a integer that increments in a for loop. I want to continue to increment `i` and append it to the end of the array being declared like so:

```
declare -a DB$iFIELDS
DB$iFIELDS[$j]=blah blah blah
```

Comment: So you want to create a new array every time in loop OR append to an existing array?

Comment: This is just creating a new (incremented) array each time. There is a separate loop that fills the array.

Comment: Ok show your code to clarify

Comment: I wrote this question to try to simplify my original here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395593/bash-text-database-file-read-in-loop

Comment: Use `printf`: `printf -v DB${i}FIELDS[$j] '%s' "blah blah blah"`. By the way, Bash is not exactly supposed to be used this way...

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf is right. If your data structures are getting this complicated (and really, it doesn't take much), it's time to pick another language.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `declare` to make the assignment as well, since to some extent the `[]` is as much a part of a variable name as it is an indexing operator.

```
$ i=3
$ declare -a DB${i}FIELDS
# ...
$ j=6
$ declare "DB${i}FIELDS[$j]=blah blah blah"
$ set | grep "DB.*FIELDS"
DB3FIELDS=([6]="blah blah blah")
```

Comment: yes, `declare` works fine with indexed (-a) and associated (-A) arrays.